# Where is Mr. Wolf seen to be present in his introduction scene in Pulp Fiction?

Tags: plot-explanation, analysis, pulp-fiction

In the scene where Mr. Wolf is sought help by Marsellus Wallace to assist Jules and Vincent to cleanup the dead body in Jimmy's house ("Bonnie's Situation"), we are shown a glimpse of the house where he resides. There seems to be a social gathering of some sort with a waitress receiving a few guests. What does Mr. Tarantino imply from this shot? Is Mr. Wolf hosting a gala of some sort? From the movie's timeline, it is pretty early in the day (before 8.00 A.M) to have such a social gathering.

And not to forget he was neatly dressed at the moment he received the call too.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The precise location isn't given but the implication from the [**script**](http://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/pulp_fiction.html) is that it's a hotel room hosting a, presumably illegal, floating crap game (or at least gambling activity).

```
           INT. HOTEL SUITE – MORNING

           The CAMERA looks through the bedroom doorway of a hotel suite 
           into the main area. We SEE a crap game being played on a 
           fancy crap table by GAMBLERS in tuxedos and LUCKY LADIES in 
           fancy evening gowns. The CAMERA PANS to the right revealing: 
           Sitting on a bed, phone in hand with his back to us, the 
           tuxedo-clad WINSTON WOLF aka "THE WOLF". We also see The 
           Wolf has a small notepad that he jots details in.
```

This seems logical since we know he is within 30<sup>*</sup> minutes of [**1265 Riverside Drive Toluca Lake in California**](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/1265+W+Riverside+Dr,+Burbank,+CA+91506,+USA/@34.1586778,-118.3837393,12z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x80c2bfee6356fe11:0x50560e518f21adc2!8m2!3d34.1586778!4d-118.3137015)....so it seems likely it's in Los Angeles...where gambling is strictly controlled.

<sup>*Or 9 minutes and 37 seconds as Mr. Wolf drives</sup>

Background sound confirms something similar..you can hear someone say "Place your bets" and "Pass the shoe" which..in this instance would indicate that, in the movie,  something else was substituted for a craps table although I'm not sure what.

Comment: According to Google, "pass the shoe" is a phrase used in the game Baccarat.

Comment: That was what I originally thought but the action and other sound didn't seem to fit...